# Javascript trouble passing select box value to object parameter

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm getting stuck on getting the newGame function to run and I have no idea what's stopping it.

I have a select box that has 3 levels, but every time I run the newGame function which reaches out the the selected level, it always returns level 1, even when I have the select box with value 3.

I can't figure out why this isn't working? The most maddening part is that I had this working before but somehow I did something that stopped it from working. Any help I am grateful! I'm open to general criticism on the code structure as well.
Thanks!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    (function (){

        var levelSelected = $('.gameLevel :selected'),
            newGameSelected = $('.start');


        newGameSelected.on('click', function() { abc.newGame(); })

        var abc = {

            level : levelSelected.val(),

            abcArray : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p'],

            createLevel : function(){   
                console.log('test');
            },

            newGame : function (){
                var level = this.level;
                console.log('Doin level #: ' + level);
            }


        }


    })();

    })
```

Comment: Your script looks valid, but can we see your HTML for the sake of clarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you only get the `$('.gameLevel :selected')` when page loads. When you change selection and click on `.start`, this selection **is not refreshed**. To fix this, you have to re-get the `$('.gameLevel :selected').val()` everytime you click on the `.start`. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    (function (){
        var newGameSelected = $('.start');
        newGameSelected.on('click', function() { 
                       abc.level = $('.gameLevel :selected').val();
                       abc.newGame(); 
        })
        var abc = {
            abcArray : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p'],
            createLevel : function(){   
                console.log('test');
            },
            newGame : function (){
                var level = this.level;
                console.log('Doin level #: ' + level);
            }
        }
    })();
```

});

Or

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
        (function (){
            var newGameSelected = $('.start');
            newGameSelected.on('click', function() { 
                           abc.newGame($('.gameLevel :selected').val()); 
            })
            var abc = {
                abcArray : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p'],
                createLevel : function(){   
                    console.log('test');
                },
                newGame : function (level){
                    console.log('Doin level #: ' + level);
                }
            }
        })();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

place  this line

```
var levelSelected = $('.gameLevel :selected')
```

inside

```
newGame : function (){
   var levelSelected = $('.gameLevel :selected');
   var level =levelSelected.val();
   console.log('Doin level #: ' + level);
}
```